# How to size Angular CDK overlay backdrop when attaching to component

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I want to have a CDK overlay over a specific component.  I using `flexibleConnectedTo()` to position the content portion of the overlay correctly over the component.  I cannot figure out how to have the overlay backdrop *only* cover the component instead of the entire page.  The `cdk-overlay-container` class has CSS as

```
pointer-events: none;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

I know I could override the CSS, however what I am looking for is an Angular CDK way of sizing the `cdk-overlay-container` to fit the boundaries of a component.

I read through the documentation, however I don't see a way to do this.  Am I missing something from the docs?

Answer (score 5):

An Angular CDK way of sizing `cdk-overlay-container` is to provide your custom css class to **OverlayConfig**, there is **backdropClass** and **panelClass** properties.

```
 let overlayRef = this.overlay.create({
     backdropClass: 'your-custom-overlay-class',
     panelClass: 'your-custom-panel-class'
 });
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much for this, i have been searching for a solution to alter the styling of cdk-overlay for popup without effecting other popups, this works man thank you

Comment: This is cool, but definitely does not answer the question. You would need to know the size of the component. I still cant figure out how to size the overlay on just the component

Answer (score 0):

For MatDialog you can specify backdropClass separately using **backdropClass** property.
Example:

```
const dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PopupDialogComponent, any> = this.dialog.open(
  PopupDialogComponent,
  {

    id: "dialog",
    width: "470px",
    height: "12rem",
    autoFocus: false,
    disableClose: true,
    backdropClass: 'Your-css-class-for-backdrop',
    data: {
      isDeleteWorkcell: true,
      ErrorMessage: "",
      deleteMsg: "Permanently remove from “Shared with me”?",
      deleteHeader: "Remove Sharing",
      deleteBtnTxt: "Yes, remove"
    }
  }
);
```